# PHP-DI not able to wire interface to implementation w/ slim bridge

Tags: php, dependency-injection, slim, php-di

I'm coming from the world of .net and DI/IOC containers like autofac, ninject etc.

I expect, and `php-di`'s documentation seems to imply the following should work:

index.php / front controller

```php
$containerBuilder = new DI\ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([

    ListRepositoryInterface::class => DI\get(ListRepository::class)
]);

$app = DI\Bridge\Slim\Bridge::create($container);

$app->get('/list', [HelloWorldController::class, 'get']);

$app->run();
```

The "controller as a service" in question:

```php
/*
* HelloWorldController
*/
class HelloWorldController
{
    private $listRepository;

    public function __construct(ListRepositoryInterface $listRepository)
    {
        $this->listRepository = $listRepository;
    }

    public function get(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $lists = $this->listRepository->getAllForUser(0);
        $json = json_encode($lists);

        $response->getBody()->write($json);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

The interface and implementation, in one code chunk for brevity:

```php
interface ListRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getAllForUser($userId);
}

class ListRepository implements ListRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getAllForUser($userId) 
    {
        return [
                [
                    'name' => 'a list'
                ]
            ];
    }
}
```

When I run this w/ the php development server and hit `<addr>/list`, I get (with a few line breaks for visualization and cleanup of my personal info):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught DI\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinition: Entry "ToDo\Controllers\HelloWorldController" cannot be resolved: Entry "Todo\DataAccess\Contracts\ListRepositoryInterface" 
cannot be resolved: the class is not instantiable Full definition: Object ( class = #NOT INSTANTIABLE# Todo\DataAccess\Contracts\ListRepositoryInterface lazy = false ) Full definition: Object ( class = ToDo\Controllers\HelloWorldController lazy = false 
__construct( $listRepository = get(Todo\DataAccess\Contracts\ListRepositoryInterface) ) ) in /Users/<user>/src/php-todo/app/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Exception/InvalidDefinition.php:18 
Stack trace: #0 /Users/<user>/src/php-todo/app/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ObjectCreator.php(155): 
DI\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinition::create(Object(DI\Definition\ObjectDefinition), 'Entry "ToDo\\Con...') #1 /Users/<user>/src/php-todo/app/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Resolver/ObjectCreator.php(71): DI\Definition\Resolver\Objec in /Users/<user>/src/php-todo/app/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Definition/Exception/InvalidDefinition.php on line 18
```

This seems to be implying that my call to `addDefinitions` is not being in any way shape or form respected. I have tried `DI\get`, `DI\autowire`, `DI\create` and anything else I can find..... I have no additional registrations, I have no additional ANYTHING interesting.

All of `php-di`'s documentation says (like all DI frameworks *should*): "type hint the interface and register the concrete type to use" but all of their examples of the slim-bridge simply show a class being injected (which is quite a bit less useful IMO). To this point ***if I change the `HelloController` to accept a ctor param of `ListRepository` instead of `ListRepositoryInterface` everything works as expected.***

Am I just bad at php and I don't understand interfaces and type hinting? Am I bad a php-di? Am I doing something that php developers would consider to be insane? Is I simply misinterpreting everything and looking at it through c# colored glasses?

Comment: small update.... as of this point, if i put all of this code into one file, everything works. Could it be a side effect of some PSR-4 autoloading not working how i expect it to?

Answer (score 0):

ok, this was an issue w/ autoloading and VERY specifically with a namespace issue. I am building a "todo" app to learn some php-specific basics.... so I have a root namespace of `ToDo`. I am following PSR-4 conventions BUT I declared the interface in a namespace of `Todo`.

The casing mis-match was causing some unexpected (to me) behaviors.... this makes sense given php is interpreted etc but I didn't realize *just how lazy* the instantiation of the class was going to be. Basically the fully qualified name I registered didn't match with the actual interface's declartion

I can use `ToDo\InterfaceThing` but have a `Todo\InterfaceThing` declared in a `src/InterfaceThing.php` file and it won't blow up.... until it tries to match the two types against each other and sees that `ToDo` and `Todo` aren't the same.

Essentially, where I was would have expected a "type not found error" (the Repository::class line) I ended up registering a non-existent type, which will never be matched because it does not exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with autoloading, when I made changes to `composer.json` section `"autoload": {"psr-4": { "App\\": "app" }}` and forgot to do `composer dumpautoload`.